# Can "hybrid" be removed/disabled from Lexus RX400h?

Tags: toyota, lexus

Where I live I've seen a few hybrid '07/'08 Lexus RX400h in very good condition. The reason I haven't looked at them is because I'm wary of the *hybrid* technology; I simply don't want to mess with that.

Is it possible to disable or remove the hybrid from Lexus RX400h so that I don't have to deal with that?

Comment: The tech is pretty good though; is there anything in particular you're concerned about? For any specific vehicle, another thing you could do is search forums and sales sites for reviews, if there's any quirks to a specific vehicle you'll certainly find them with some research (always a good idea before buying a vehicle anyways). In any case you're going to run into *way* more issues trying to remove the electric half of a hybrid than you would just using the vehicle as it was designed.

Comment: The issue is that it's been recalled for that same technology. It's an 8-yr old car with inverter technology that only specialized mechanics know about. There are too many issues with the hybrid technology.

Comment: Negative. You mean there are too many issues with the [RX400h](http://repairpal.com/recall/13V396000), not with hybrid technology in general. And the recall repaired the issue, which was a problem with solder joints, not with hybrid technology or the drive system itself. So perhaps you should be suspicious of "soldering technology" instead. :P

Comment: Toyota's HSD (Hybrid Synergy Drive) which I think Lexus uses is said to be exceptionally reliable so you do not need to fear any problems like with used turbo-diesel cars etc. Also at least on the Prius hybrid the battery cells of the battery pack can be changed separately so in case the battery should be in "bad" condition it usually only is needed to change a single batt cell for few dollars.

Answer (score 2):

If you have not yet purchased a hybrid vehicle and do not want a hybrid equipped vehicle can I reasonably suggest you purchase a non-hybrid vehicle.  If you like the RX400h, perhaps an RX300 would suit your needs.

Theoretically it would be possible to remove hybrid technology from a hybrid equipped vehicle but this would be very time consuming and costly.  It is not possible to remove hybrid technology from a hybrid vehicle without "mess[ing] with" hybrid technology.

Comment: What would happen if the battery dies or if the electric motor/generator stopped working? Would I be able to drive in some sort of a "limp" mode.

Comment: @rana: Nope, everything turns off and it just stops moving wherever you are (or at least that's what I've read). That's the biggest issue.

Comment: It's not that I don't want a hybrid vehicle; I don't want an 8-yr old hybrid that's been recalled for the *hybrid* technology because it shuts down when the battery fails.

Comment: @rbhatup If you actually read the recall, you'll see the issue was with [poor choice of solder for high temperature environments](http://repairpal.com/recall/13V396000). And then the recall fixed it. So perhaps you should just avoid all vehicles that have wires soldered to things and get, say, a pre-ECU vehicle from the 40's or 50's with no electronics. There was never a recall for low battery issues. If you don't want an RX400h then don't buy an RX400h, there's plenty of other vehicles that exist besides that one.

Comment: I didn't read the recall, I read what happens when the battery fails and you're in a 5-lane highway with other cars going at 70mph. I read what happens if the inverter or any other hybrid part fails and I'm out-of-warranty. That's what I read.

Comment: @rbhatup it sounds to me like you've talked yourself out of an RX400h.  If you are so worried about the vehicle then you won't enjoy owning it because every strange noise it makes, everytime a warning light pops up and every time it's inspected or serviced, you'll be convinced it'll fail.  I personally could enjoy owning a vehicle I was so worried about so perhaps you would be better with something else.

Comment: You're simply upset because I don't agree with you. You're not a Lexus salesman, so why are you trying to sell me a car?

Comment: I had a specific question, and you answered it; I appreciate it. But arguing with me because I have an opinion that doesn't match yours is out-of-context and out-of-topic.